# How to Select All or Default on where clause

Tags: sql-server, count, where-clause

I have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(r.id) 
FROM [Reg] r 
JOIN Users u 
    ON r.userId = u.id 
WHERE 
    u.organisationId IN ({0})
```

If there is an `id` for ({0}) then return the count for that organisation otherwise return the count for all organisations.

This script works for the organisations separately but for all organisations the number is smaller then the correct count for few records.And I don't understand why?

EDIT: Maybe we can make it if the organisationId is defined return the count for that organisation, and the organisationId is all then return All

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expected result?

Comment: I call this from a function. If the organization id is defined I get the count for that otherwise I get the count for all organisation.

Comment: Are u using {0} as a variable like **u.organisationId IN (@csvvalues)**? or is it hardcoded like **u.organisationId IN (1,2)**? @Ahmed H Mehiny

Comment: I am using this {0} not hard coded.